# Using survey package in R, when I run unadjusted svyglm (regression model), I get results but when full adjusted std error returnes Inf

Tags: r, survey

So this code works:

```
unadjustedmodel <-svyglm (HASMM ~ periocat3,
                             family = gaussian(),
                             data   = nhanesDesign,
                             design = ageDesign)
tab_model(unadjustedmodel)
```

But this code returns Inf as standard errors:

```
interactmodelsmmi <- svyglm (HASMM ~ periocat3 + RIAGENDR +  RIDAGEYR + DXDTOBMD  + BMXBMI + relevel(smoking, ref="Non-Smoker") +
                    relevel(diabcat, ref = "Non-diabetes") + education + DR1TKCAL + DR1TPROT + LBXVIDMS,RIAGENDR*RIDAGEYR + DXDTOBMD*MGDCGSZ,
                    family = gaussian(),
                    data   = nhanesDesign,
                    design = ageDesign,
                    df=degf(nhanesDesign),
                    na.action=na.exclude
                    )
```

Where could be problem?

I also try to specify the degrees of freedom but it didn't work.
Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You're estimating more parameters than you have degrees of freedom, so using the standard estimate of residual degrees of freedom, yours are negative.

Specifying `df` to the `svyglm` call won't get you anywhere; `svyglm` doesn't have a `df=` argument.  You specify the degrees of freedom to the `summary` method, eg

```
summary(interactmodelsmi, df.resid=degf(ageDesign))
```

I should also note that `svyglm` doesn't have a `data=` argument. Whichever design object you actually want to use should be specified in the `design=` argument.

And finally, getting `Inf` standard errors rather than just `NA` p-values in this situation is a sign that you're using an old version of the package and you should update it. Version 4.1-1 has been on CRAN for well over a year.